# How to use PHP's set_include_path and multi directory library

Tags: php, phpseclib

So I am using [PHP Secure Communications Library 2.0](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0/phpseclib) in a project and it is being used in a number of places (different files in different subdirectories)

Currently, to make it work I copy the 5 directories and 1 file into each sub-directory then include using `include('Net/SSH2.php');`  I'm sure this is incorrect.

The documentation says to use the following:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
```

but I cannot get that to work.

I have a file `/var/www/test.php` and I have `/var/www/phpseclib`

What I've done so far.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo get_include_path();  //Gets me .:
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('10.0.0.15');  //A valid IP for an SFTP host on the network
```

That results in **Fatal error: Class 'Net_SFTP' not found in /var/www/test.php...**

So then I moved the phpseclib directory to `/tmp` and change to `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/tmp/phpseclib');`

`$sftp = new Net_SFTP('10.0.0.15');` Still results in **Fatal error: Class 'Net_SFTP' not found in /var/www/test.php...**

So my structure is:
(Permissions on all of the files in /Users/jason/tmp are set appropriately.)

```
/Users/jason/tmp/phpseclib
/Users/jason/tmp/phpseclib/Crypt
/Users/jason/tmp/phpseclib/File
/Users/jason/tmp/phpseclib/Math
/Users/jason/tmp/phpseclib/Net
/Users/jason/tmp/phpseclib/System
/Users/jason/tmp/phpseclib/openssl.cnf

/var/www/test.php
/var/www/A/two.php
```

And I want to use phpseclib in both `test.php` AND `two.php` and I feel like all I should need to do is add...

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/tmp/phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
```

...to the top of each and be good to go.  What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: Files in `/tmp/` get automatically deleted every day per http://askubuntu.com/a/759048/180177 . Maybe `/var/www/phpseclib` would be better? Also, I'd double check the permissions too. Make sure that www-data or whatever user Apache is running as can access that directory.

Comment: Actually...  are you using the 2.0 branch from git? If that's the case then you shouldn't be following the directions on http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ - you should be using an autoloader. Composer would be ideal but you can do it without composer. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/2.0.html for more info.

Comment: @neubert Thanks, I updated the question, /tmp was me being lazy.  I am using the 2.0 branch so I'll check out the autoloader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to load the library in a number of different places is through the use of an autoloader.

Composer is suggested by phpseclib and is very easy to setup.
You can download composer from here: https://getcomposer.org/download/

Once you have composer setup, the next thing you need to do is create a composer.json file in the root of your project. Sub out 2.0.* for whatever version you would like to use.

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*"
    }
}
```

Available versions can be found here: https://packagist.org/packages/phpseclib/phpseclib

Once you have created this file you need to run one of these commands in your terminal to generate everything you need to autoload the library. The command will depend on how your system is setup.

```
composer install
        or
php composer.phar install
```

Once you've ran this command a vendor folder will be generated with all of the required libraries you specified. (In this case just phpseclib.)

The last few changes that need to be made are in your index.php file.

Change

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
```

To

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \phpseclib\Net\SFTP;
```

which will allow you to access the SFTP function in the phpseclib folder.
Additionally depending on what version you are using some of the nomenclature has changed.

If you are using 2.0.* you need to change

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP($ihost);
```

To

```
$sftp = new SFTP($ihost);
```